# unable to render my components when using with ROUTE in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

[image: image showing react app]code for app.js .. i have been trying to use ROUTE but unable to render my components

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Rooms from './pages/Rooms';
import SingleRoom from './pages/SingleRoom';
import Error from './pages/Error';
import { Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact  path="/rooms/" component={Rooms}/>
      <Route exactpath="/singleroom" component={SingleRoom}/>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide https://codesandbox.io/ so we can check your code more efficiently.

Comment: Since react-router-dom changes often, also tell us which version you are using.

Comment: To validate the installed version please run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` from your project's directory. If there are any errors in the console when running your code please also share that. Please also edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `Route`s in the `Router` and `Routes` components.

This is for react-router-dom v6:

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Rooms from './pages/Rooms';
import SingleRoom from './pages/SingleRoom';
import Error from './pages/Error';
import { Routes, Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/rooms/" element={<Rooms />} />
        <Route path="/singleroom" element={<SingleRoom />}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i was trying but not working

Comment: hey thanks its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already wrapped your app with `<Router>` inside your index.js file,  now every time you use routes You need to wrap them with `<Switch>`

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route exact  path="/rooms/" component={Rooms}/>
    <Route exactpath="/singleroom" component={SingleRoom}/>
</Switch>
```